# Immutable objects with Mutable fields

Tags: java, wrapper, immutability

The Setup: I am attempting to write a value object, so I figured it would be best to make it immutable. This object has a `BigDecimal`, so:

```
public class MyValueObject {
    private final BigDecimal bob;

    public MyValueObject() {
        bob = new BigDecimal(0);
    }
}
```

I have also written a handful of methods, including an add method, that return new `MyValueObject`s. Here is an example of one:

```
public MyValueObject add(BigDecimal augend) {
        return new MyValueObject(this.bob.add(augend);
}
```

The question is, does this effectively set `bob` or is it returning a completely new `MyValueObject` with an entirely new `BigDecimal` as expected?

Comment: Well if it didn't function this way then how would you create immutable objects?

Comment: I could also have written the method as something like: `BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(this.interval.longValue()); return new MyValueObject(d.add.(augend));` no? The question is are they doing something different?

Comment: The `BigDecimal` object is itself immutable (the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) says so).  So if you're worried that your operation will change the instance variable in your value object, you don't need to.  Specifically, the `add` method of `BigDecimal` creates a new `BigDecimal` and does not change the original one.  Is that what your question is about?

Comment: Ahhh, so it wouldn't matter how I got an instance of `BigDecimal`, it will always be a new one. I was vaguely under the impression that it was mutable for some reason, but never thought to check the javadoc. You know, this thing I've got open here next to my IDE windows. Go figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use "new", you are creating a new object.  So It is returning a completely new MyValueObject which utilizes "bob", but is not the same.

Comment: So it is utilizing it's own instance of `bob`, correct?

Comment: yes, it would be using its own instance of "bob."  I'm assuming the method is in class MyValueObject by the way, otherwise the code wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, the method is, your assumption is correct. Thanks for helping clarify that in my head. I'll accept your answer as soon as SO allows.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have a Java editor around so forgive the example.  Sometimes it is kind of useful to use a static "builder" in cases like this and make the constructor private.

```
public class ValueObject {
    private int bob;

    private ValueObject(int bob) {
        this.bob = bob;
    }

    public static ValueObject Create(int value){
        return new ValueObject(value);
    }

    public ValueObject Add(int increaseBy) {
        return ValueObject.Create(this.bob + increaseBy);
    }
}
```

I realised I didn't answer the question.  You would be creating a new object.  My answer was intended to make the "creating" more clear in the code which will make it more clear to you.

Comment: This appears to be a good answer to an entirely different question.

Comment: UPDATE AFTER EDIT: Got you. That did help. Thanks!